# Variable accessible in component but undefined in template

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to check for a value from my database before displaying a form using ngIf. I already fetched the values and confirmed it as it appears in my console when i `console.log` it. But when I bind it to my ngIf directive, it says `"cannot read property of undefined"` though it still gives the expected behavior.

My component:

```
ngOnInit() {
   let p = {
        user: this.userInfo.reg_no,
        key: '06'
   }
   this.data.postMethod(p).subscribe(
        data => {
          data['code'] != '00' ? this.clearanceInfo = null : 
          this.clearanceInfo = data['message'][0];
          console.log(this.clearanceInfo)
        }
   );
}
```

my template:

```
<mat-card *ngIf='clearanceInfo.dad == 0'>
    <form>
          //*********//
    </form>
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> cannot read property of undefined

This error is caused because when the view is rendered `clearanceInfo` property is still `undefined`, and you are trying to access a property of that `undefined` value.

You can use Angular's [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) `?` to prevent that view render failure if the value is `null` or `undefined`.

```
*ngIf='clearanceInfo?.dad == 0'
```

Adding the `?` operator will fix that error.